# Is there a way to memorize a subSequence into a variable?

Tags: java, subsequence

I'm making a program that should ignore `(` and `)` in words (without the use of RegExp), and through the method I created, I want my variable `x` to memorize the new String. How can I access subSequence in such way or circumvent my issue through another method that doesn't include the use of RegExp?

```java
public int removeParentheses(char[] str) {
    // To keep track of '(' and ')' characters count 
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
        if (str[i] != '(' && str[i] != ')')
            str[count++] = str[i];

    return count;
}

public String foo(String input) {

    for (String index : input.split(" ")) {
        char[] charArray = index.toCharArray();
        int k = removeParentheses(charArray);
        String x = String.valueOf(charArray).subSequence(0, k); // that's what i want to do. it doesn't work.
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(charArray).subSequence(0, k)); // this is the only way i can make it work, but it doesn't suffice my needs
    }
}
```

The current output is

```
 error: incompatible types: CharSequence cannot be converted to String
                        String x = String.valueOf(charArray).subSequence(0, k);
                                                                        ^
1 error
```

I expect the output of `boo)` to be `boo` in my `x` variable, not just on-screen through the `System.out.println` method.

Comment: You're using `CharSequence#subSequence` which returns a `CharSequence`. Use `String#substring` instead as it returns `String`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said this is *"what i want to do. it doesn't work."*:

```
String x = String.valueOf(charArray).subSequence(0, k);
```

The return value of [`subSequence()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#subSequence(int,%20int)) is a [`CharSequence`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html) which is not a String. It makes sense that it wouldn't work.

Since you are starting from an array of characters – `char []` – you could use [`Arrays.copyOfRange()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange(char[],%20int,%20int)) to create a new array of some smaller subset of `charArray`, like this:

```
char[] copy = Arrays.copyOfRange(charArray, 0, k);
```

From there, you could construct a new `String` – `new String(copy)` – or possibly just use that new character array directly.